# Wordpress и статические страницы + SESSION

Tags: wordpress

Есть некторая статическая страница. По умолчанию она является главной.
Как можно сделать так, чтобы при заходе на эту страницу юзеру ставилась сессяи с параметром, и в последующий заход на эту же страницу его редиректило на другую. Типа что то на подобии A/B тестирования.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так и сделать. в сессию записать флажок

```
$_SESSION['mainpage']=1
```

и если в сессии флаг уже есть

```
 if isset(isset($_SESSION['mainpage']) {header('location: otherpage.php');exit;}
```

выдавать заголовок редиректа. если надо ещё и самому пользователю привязать (авторизованному) то  в его свойства записать этот флаг и при авторизации записывать его в сессию.

Comment: Это понятно. Не понятно где именно это вставлять. В каком файле?

Comment: в файле главной страницы. поближе к началу, сначала условие, потом присваивание.

Comment: И как он называется? То что в корне ВП лежит index.php ?

Comment: в шаблоне header.php изменил